# Withdrawal sol to the wrong address, please help to recover lost fund

Tags: transactions, transfer

I send some sol to a wrong address that is missing one letter. I still can see the sol stay this address(GDTXXE91yZ5k8k2FsbLNDuijZymRQy2psJHgqm1CBor) and it is owned System Program in solscan.io which the account is 11111111111111111111111111111111.
Is there any way I can recover my SOL?